# how do i join 2 tables using sql

Tags: sql

I have table 1:

```
 col1     col2
 a        a1
 a        a2
 a        a3
```

and table 2:

```
 col1     col3
 a        a1
 a        a4
```

I want to join table 1 and table 2 to get table 3:

```
 col1     col2    col3
 a        a1       a1
 a        a2       null
 a        a3       null
 a        null     a4
```

how can i get table 3 using a sql join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.col1, t2.col1) as col1, t1.col2, t2.col3
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get them with a [left join and a right join](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) and then [union](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) them together.

The left join ensures we get all rows in table1 regardless of whether they have a matching row in table2. And the right join gets all rows in table2 regardless of whether they have a matching row in table1. Then we mash them together with `union` which will also remove duplicates.

Left join.

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
  on t1.col1 = t2.col1
 and t1.col2 = t2.col3

+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
| a    | a1   | a1   |
| a    | a2   | NULL |
| a    | a3   | NULL |
+------+------+------+
```

Right join. Note that we must select t2.col1 because t1.col will be null.

```
select t2.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3
from table1 t1
right join table2 t2
  on t1.col1 = t2.col1
 and t1.col2 = t2.col3

+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
| a    | a1   | a1   |
| a    | NULL | a4   |
+------+------+------+
```

Union.

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
  on t1.col1 = t2.col1
 and t1.col2 = t2.col3
union
select t2.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3
from table1 t1
right join table2 t2
  on t1.col1 = t2.col1
 and t1.col2 = t2.col3

+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
| a    | a1   | a1   |
| a    | a2   | NULL |
| a    | a3   | NULL |
| a    | NULL | a4   |
+------+------+------+
```

It's instructive to run these with `select *` to see the full contents of each query.

Comment: thanks Schwern this works fine just that Gordon Linoff's does it at once thank both of you for help